# How to stop sessionStorage from saving the values after a limit is reached

Tags: jquery, html, session-storage, sessionstorage

I've been trying to figure out how can I stop the sessionStorage from saving the values after the `max_fields` is reached when the `Add Another Worker` button is clicked? It seems after the limit is reached and the button is clicked again the values keep getting added to the sessionStorage I was wondering how can I stop this from happening.

Here is a link to my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p2euLqbf/4/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="worker-container-last">
            <label class="worker-label">
                <select name="title[]" class="title">
                    <option value="Select a Title" selected="selected">Select a Title</option>
                    <option value="Boss">Boss</option>
                    <option value="Worker">Worker</option>
                    <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="add-more"></div>
        <div><a class="worker" title="" href="">Add Another Worker</a></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JQuery

```
var worker_record = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
    workerData();
    $('.worker').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var title = $('.title:first').val();            

        var someData = {title: title};
        worker_record.push(someData);

        sessionStorage.worker = JSON.stringify(worker_record);
        workerData();
    });

    function workerData(){
        var max_fields = 6;
        var x = 1;

        if(!(typeof sessionStorage.worker === 'undefined' || sessionStorage.worker.length<1)){
            worker_record = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.worker);
        }

        $('.add-more').empty();
        for(var i=0; i<worker_record.length; i++){
            if(x < max_fields){
                x++;
                var title = worker_record[i].title;

                var worker = '<select name="title[]" class="title title-options"><option value="Select a Title" selected="selected">Select a Title</option><option value="Boss">Boss</option><option value="Worker">Worker</option><option value="Manager">Manager</option></select>';

                $('.add-more').append(worker);
                $('.title:eq('+$('.title-options').length+')').val(title);
            }
        }

        $('.title:first').val('Select a Title');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set a limit you can do this .

set a variable first

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem("limit") === null) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('limit', 0);
}
```

Increment the this variable value on every iteration and set a check of limit accordingly 
Suppose you want to set a `limit = 10` then,

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem('limit') <= 10 )
{
 var count = sessionStorage.getItem('limit');
     count++;

 sessionStorage.setItem('limit', count);

  //do whatever

}
else{

   alert("session limit reached!");
   return false;

 }
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/p2euLqbf/12/)

[image]

Comment: Exactly where would I place the `sessionStorage.setItem('limit', 0);` thanks,

Comment: @obi : added in answer

Comment: @obi : check if that variable is  set  or not. then set it wherever you like to .. or you can set it in your first iteration too with value 1

Comment: forgive me I might be to tired I cant seem to figure out where to place this code.

Comment: @obi : ok,, checkout the demo I have added https://jsfiddle.net/p2euLqbf/6/

Comment: This still adds the values to the sessionStorage.

Comment: @obi : are you sure ? it doesnt add after 5 adds.. check out the pic in answer

Comment: I'm sure I checked in chromes session storage it keeps adding them.

Comment: @obi : and this is my chrome pic http://puu.sh/qpyaT/e8f85eb434.png works for me ... that might be cache . please clear .. or try in new cognito window

Comment: Right click your mouse and pick inspect and choose Application and pick session storage you will see the values there.

Comment: ok i did not notice what you doing in your on click function . so here's your final answer https://jsfiddle.net/p2euLqbf/12/